# How do I prevent exceptions from causing a transaction rollback under Grails?

Tags: grails, transactions, grails-orm

My Grails service is having an issue where a swallowed exception unrelated to a transaction is causing the transaction to rollback even when it is unrelated to the persistance of the domain object.

In my service I have something along the lines of

```
updateSomething(domainObj) {
    def oldFilename = domainObj.filename
    def newFilename = getNewFilename()

    domainObj.filename = newFilename
    domainObj.save(flush: true)

    try {
        cleanUpOldFile(oldFilename)
    } catch (cleanupException) {
        // oh well, log and swallow
    }
}
```

What I am seeing is that when I have exception when I am cleaning up the old file, I log it and swallow it, but it still causes the transaction to rollback, even though I am already done updating the domain object.

How do I limit the scope transaction to complete before the clean up or is there another way to get the clean up exception to not cause a rollback?

Just for the record I am using Grails 2.1.1

Comment: This problem can result in a "org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy -
no Session". I thought I had my exceptions caught properly, not realizing the location of my try/catch was too late!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use annotations to do more fine-grained transaction demarcation. By default services are transactional, and all public methods are transactional. But if you use any `@Transactional` annotations, Grails doesn't make everything transactional - you have complete control.

Runtime exceptions automatically trigger rollbacks, but checked exceptions don't. Even though Groovy doesn't required that you catch checked exceptions, the feature is a Spring thing which doesn't know about Groovy exception handling.

Transactions are implemented by wrapping your service class instance in a proxy. If an exception "escapes" the proxy, whether it's then caught or not, the rollback will have already happened.

So you have a few options. Annotate `updateSomething` as `@Transactional` but don't annotate `cleanUpOldFile`:

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional

@Transactional
def updateSomething(domainObj) {
...
}

def cleanUpOldFile(...) {
   ...
}
```

You can also annotate cleanUpOldFile with one or more unchecked exceptions that shouldn't roll back a transaction (or in other use cases checked exceptions that should), e.g.

```
@Transactional(noRollbackFor=[FooException, BarException])
def cleanUpOldFile(...) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: One thing I don't fully understand, shouldn't my catch block catch all exceptions, both runtime and checked? How does Spring even know I have any exceptions?

Comment: I assume it is noticing the exception between service layers, in my case I had one service layer talking to another. That's the only thing that makes sense to me.

Comment: If all you do is add @Transactional(noRollbackFor=[FooException, BarException]) to cleanUpOldFile(), what effect does that have on every other method in the class?  Are they still transactional or not?

Comment: If I specify `noRollbackFor=[Exception]`, will this still rollback for an uncaught exception?

Comment: Since Grails v3.2.0, checked exceptions also trigger rollbacks. [source](https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/services.html#_declarative_transactions)

Answer (score 8):

In addition to [@Burt Beckwith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/160313/burt-beckwith)'s answer, if you have a service where you just don't want transactions (which I actually did in my case) you can turn off transactions on all public methods by adding

```
static transactional = false
```

to the Service class.

Comment: Yep, that's very common for utility services that don't write to the database. It's a good performance optimization since otherwise you incur a small cost of creating an unnecessary transaction for each call.