# Grails transaction wokflow

Tags: spring, grails, groovy, transactions, spring-transactions

I have a scheduler code(In grails) which runs inside transaction block:

```
Plan.withTransaction{
.....
plan.save(failOnError: true)
transaction.save(failOnError: true)
try{
  smsService.sendSMS(transaction) // transactional service
}catch(Exception e){
}
..........
}
```

Inside the sendSMS method:

```
def sendSMS(Transaction transaction){
try{
  getSMSContent()
  sendSms()
 }  catch(Exception e){  print ...exception catched here....   }

}



 String getSMSContent(...){
    ..... it throws exception in some cases

 }
```

Now the issue is that plan and transaction is not saved(validate returns ok with no errors) if `getSMSContent()` throws exception. I think the transaction should not roll back because we catched the exception in the same service. Do I need to catch the exception in the same method which is getSMSContent so that transaction does not rollback and plan/transaction is saved even if sms is failed ?

Or should I mark the sms service as "Requires_New" so that new transaction gets created ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I prevent exceptions from causing a transaction rollback under Grails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15823677/how-do-i-prevent-exceptions-from-causing-a-transaction-rollback-under-grails)

Comment: @doelleri The scenario is different here. I am calling a service method which calls another method. Exception is thrown from 2nd method and caught in 1st method of sms service. The answer says that "If an exception "escapes" the proxy, whether it's then caught or not, the rollback will have already happened." Not sure what that means. Also in my case the exception is thrown and caught in sms service.

Comment: Which Grails version?

Comment: Grails version is 2.4.3

Comment: Did you ever find the solution?

Comment: @nasch Yes, I did at that time only. Grails transactional behavior is a bit different. It rolls back the transaction if the exception moves out of the method. To prevent it, we have to catch it within the same method. Better solution was to mark the service as requires_new so that new transaction gets created.